# Given a symmetric matrix $A$, are there any matrices $B$, $C$ that $BAC = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a $4 \times 4$ symmetric matrix $A$, are there any matrices $B,C$ that:
$BAC = I_{4}$ ?

I've thought of $B$ being a orthogonal matrix $P$ ($B=P$) and $ C = P^{T}$ so we get
$PAP^{T} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1}&0&0&0\\0&\lambda_{2}&0&0\\0&0&\lambda_{3}&0\\0&0&0&\lambda_{4}\end{bmatrix} $
Where $\lambda_{i}$ with $i \in {1,2,3,4}$ are the eigenvalues of matrix $A$.

And then demanded that $\{\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\lambda_{3},\lambda_{4}\} = \{1,1,1,1\}$
But I am not sure that this is correct.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is true if and only if $A$ is invertible, in which case you can take $B = I$ and $C = A^{-1}$.

Comment: A is invertible ($det(A) != 0$) but is there something I can study about this? Or it's just a matter of picking the right matrices?

Comment: For *any* invertible $B$ you can find a $C$ such that the equality holds: $C=(BA)^{-1}$.

Comment: Maybe an interesting variant is to see if you can get $A=C$ and/or symmetric as well.

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then you can do this with $B = C^T$ if and only if all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.  See Sylvester's Law of Inertia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding Qiaochu Yuan's comment, suppose that A is invertible. Then we can choose $B = I, C = A^{-1}$ so that $BAC = IAA^{-1} = I$.

On the other hand, if $C$ is not invertible, then its null space is non-trivial (this follows because its a square matrix), so there exists $x \neq 0$ such that $Cx = 0$. Hence for any matrices $A,B$
$$BACx = BA0 = 0$$

If also $BAC = I$, then there would exist $x \neq 0$ such that $Ix = x = 0$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, if the identity is to hold, then $C$ must be surjective.

Now if $A$ is not invertible then again its null space is non-trivial so there exists $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax = 0$ and since $C$ is surjective there exists $y \neq 0$ such that $Cy = x$. Hence

$$BACy = BAx = B0 = 0$$

which shows that we cannot have $BAC = I$.

Alternatively, if you have seen determinants, then
$$\det(B)\det(A)\det(C) = \det(BAC) = \det(I) = 1$$
implies $A,B$ and $C$ cannot have determinant equal to $0$ and hence cannot be singular.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying a matrix left and right by freely chosen matrices can change it quite radically. Assuming you are considering matrices with entries in a field (e.g., real or complex matrices), the most useful fact to know here is that if one requires those multiplying matrices ($B,C$ in your question) to be invertible (and in particular square) then the *only* invariants are the size of the matrix, obviously, and its *rank*, that is the dimension of the space spanned by its columns. In other words for a matrix $A$ to be transformable into a matrix $A'$ by such operation is it necessary *and sufficient* that $A$ and $A'$ be of the same size and that they have the same rank. For a square matrix, the rank is equal to the size of the matrix if and only if the matrix is invertible (non-zero determinant). Therefore one can immediately answer your question with the additional requirement $B,C$ invertible as follows: since $I_4$ has rank $4$ it is necessary and sufficient that $A$ also be of rank $4$, that is invertible.

If you allow $B,C$ to be non-invertible, this can only lead to decreasing the rank of the product, which is not helpful if you are trying to obtain $I_4$ which has maximal rank, in other words if $A$ is not invertible then it will still be impossible to obtain $BAC=I_4$. So the answer to your question remains the same as with $B,C$ invertible. Note that $A$ being symmetric has no effect whatsoever on the answer.